# Problem with overwriting property in module with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, scope, this, addeventlistener

I'm having trouble writing a value to a variable inside addEventListener and using it as a object property. Key word this showing the Player object,but choice property is still null, but inside addEventListener everything works fine. Sorry for my bad english, but i realy need help.

```
export class Player{
constructor(){
    this.board = document.querySelector('.playerMoveImg');
    this.score = 0;
    this.choice = null;
}
moveChoice = () => {
    const localChoise = document.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
        if(event.target.value !== undefined){
            this.choice = event.target.value;
            this.board.style.backgroundImage =`url("src/img/Player${this.choice}.jpg")`;
        }
    })
    console.log(this.choice); //shows null //expect showing event.target.value
}
```

}

```
import {Player} from './player.js'
const player = new Player();
player.moveChoice();
```

Comment: Please always use corresponding programming language tag, so that you attract more tailored audience and others, which might have no competence in the technology in question, won't be seeing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a difference between `method` syntax and the `arrow function` syntax.

```js
export class Player{
  constructor(){
    this.board = document.querySelector('.playerMoveImg');
    this.score = 0;
    this.choice = null;
  }
  // instead of moveChoice = () => {
  // use:
  moveChoice() {
    const localChoise = document.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
      if (event.target.value !== undefined){
        this.choice = event.target.value;
        this.board.style.backgroundImage =`url("src/img/Player${this.choice}.jpg")`;

        console.log(this.choice); // we need to move this log into the callback
      }
    })
  }
}
```

the problem was that since this is bound to the parent `this` in arrow functions, and you did not had a parent scope here, it was bound to null

If you want to use an arrow function, your have to set the method during the `constructor` call:

```js
export class Player{
  constructor(){
    this.board = document.querySelector('.playerMoveImg');
    this.score = 0;
    this.choice = null;
    this.moveChoice = () => {
      // in this case, the arrow function can find the parent this
      // it will use the same one as the constructor
      const localChoise = document.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
        if (event.target.value !== undefined){
          this.choice = event.target.value;
          this.board.style.backgroundImage =`url("src/img/Player${this.choice}.jpg")`;

          console.log(this.choice); //shows null //expect showing event.target.value
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows null after your changes.

Comment: then I need to see the code where you call `moveChoice`

Comment: I have already tried to use the solution to move the function to the constructor but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is that your console.log is done before any click as been registered, so it will always be `null`.

Comment: ok, I understand but what to do to make the object remember the value from addEventListener